# Strange behaviour of boxed nullable integers

Tags: kotlin, nullable

I have a problem with nullable variable in Kotlin
I found this example in the Kotlin docs:

```
val a: Int = 100
val boxedA: Int? = a
val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a

val b: Int = 10000
val boxedB: Int? = b
val anotherBoxedB: Int? = b

println(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) // true
println(boxedB === anotherBoxedB) // false
```

output

```
true
false
```

They explain that this is the memory optimization that JVM applies to Integer s between -128 and 127. It doesn't apply to the b references, so they are different objects.

then I convert a and b to nullable

```
val a: Int? = 100
val boxedA: Int? = a
val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a

val b: Int? = 10000
val boxedB: Int? = b
val anotherBoxedB: Int? = b

println(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) // true
println(boxedB === anotherBoxedB) // true
```

output

```
true
true
```

What makes this difference? Can anyone please explain to me?

Comment: For example first see all variable data type is integer.  And second a value is 100 and then another box value equal A means a and now anotherboxA also inherit same value. For Example Variable is just like nick name. Somebody call you my hero somebody call you my star. But in reality you are same person even they call u by two different name. Same a here also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case (non-nullable), boxing occurs on all of these lines, as you have correctly identified:

```
val boxedA: Int? = a
val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a

val boxedB: Int? = b
val anotherBoxedB: Int? = b
```

This is because `Int?` generally translates to `java.lang.Integer` in Java.

So 2 new, different, instances of `java.lang.Integer` are created on the last two lines, because `b` is greater than 127.

However, in the second case with nullables, boxing only occurs on these lines:

```
val a: Int? = 100

val b: Int? = 10000
```

Note that because `a` and `b` are nullable, they are now of wrapper type `java.lang.Integer`. They are *already* boxed! So when you assign them to `boxedA`, `boxedB`, `anotherBoxedA` and `anotherBoxedB`, no boxing occurs, and no new instances of `java.lang.Integer` are created. You are just assigning a variable of type `Integer` to another variable of type `Integer`.

Therefore, there is only one instance of `java.lang.Integer` storing 10000, and that is created at the line `val b: Int? = 10000`.

It might help if you translate your Kotlin to Java:

```
Integer b = 10000; // boxing only occurs here
Integer boxedB = b;
Integer anotherBoxedB = b;
```

Comment: waoo, thank you so muchhhhhh, you just made my day